# unable to update or remove libnghttp2.x86_64 packages in OEL 8

Tags: linux, yum, update, oel

When I tried to update our OEL 8 servers, I got the following error.  I can't remove or update this package libnghttp. I have tried yum clean packages, too. whenever I run any update and upgrade in OEL servers, it always failed with this package.   Finally I have to exclude this package when I run yum update in OEL 8 servers.  I don't see this issue in RHEL 8.  Can anyone help fix this issue?

"Problem opening package libnghttp2-1.33.0-5.el8_9.x86_64.rpm
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED"

Comment: You try `--nogpgcheck` option.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue where the package is reported with a mismatched content-length.

Answer (score 0):

this was an issue in the yum OL servers, was already fixed, if you have a yum mirror please do a sync and yum clean all in the client. Try again.